# How to send data in request body in get request in Ionic http native?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I need to send some data in request body of a get request in Ionic Http native.

I am using the below code to send the get request, but this converts the data to query string.

```
this.http.get(
      'apiendpoint',
      data ,
      headers
    );
}
```

using the below plugin :

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
```

below is the link to official documentaation:

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Comment: in this case, you can send data to the post method instead of get. bcoz get always send data to queryString.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send data, you should use POST method, instead of GET method:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}
...
    this.http.post(
          'apiendpoint',
          data,
          headers
        );
    }.then(data => {
    
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);
    
      })
      .catch(error => {
    
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);
    
      });
```